# LSTM input shape error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, multiclass-classification

***I am new to machine learning and keras***. I was trying to create a LSTM model for my **classification** problem but I received this error: (I got few samples from internet and tried to modify them)

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_1: expected shape=(None, None, 30), found shape=[None, 3, 1]

This is what I need, I have a sequence like this 1,2,3,4 which 1,2,3 are my X_train and 4 is label(Y), so *I mean timestep size is 3 and each has one feature only*

**I have 30 classes for my labels**. So I expect the output to be one of these 30 classes. 64 is number of memory units.

this is my code

```
def get_lstm():
    model = Sequential()  
    model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(3, 30), return_sequences=True))  
    model.add(LSTM(64))  
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))  
    model.add(Dense(30, activation='softmax'))

X_train = user_data[:, 0:3]
X_train = np.asarray(X_train).astype(np.float32)  
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
Y_train = user_data[:, 3]    
Y_train = np.asarray(Y_train).astype(np.float32)
local_model = Mymodel.get_lstm()  
local_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
local_model.set_weights(global_weights)           
local_model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32,
                                        epochs=1)
```

please let me know if you need more information or if it s not clear. I really need your help guys, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are setting the input shape as `(3,30)` for the first LSTM. As you mentioned -

> This is what I need, I have a sequence like this 1,2,3,4 which 1,2,3 are my X_train and 4 is label(Y). *so I mean timestep size is 3 and each has one feature only*

If you have 3-time steps, and only a single feature, then you should define each sequence as such.

Also, since the model will always output a 30 length probability distribution but your y_train is a single value (out of unique 30 classes), you need to use the loss `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead of `categorical_crossentropy`. [Read more here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other).

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

#Dummy data and its shapes
X = np.random.random((100,3,1)) #(100,3,1)
y = np.random.randint(0,29,(100,)) #(100,)

#Design model
inp = layers.Input((3,1))
x = layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(inp)
x = layers.LSTM(64)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
out = layers.Dense(30, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inp, out)

#Compile and fit
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32,epochs=3)
```

```
Epoch 1/3
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 3.4005 - accuracy: 0.0400
Epoch 2/3
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 3.3953 - accuracy: 0.0700
Epoch 3/3
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 3.3902 - accuracy: 0.0900
```

```
utils.plot_model(model, show_layer_names=False, show_shapes=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I came up with some brain storming :) . I did your solution before this is the error for input (3,1):  ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 30) are incompatible. thanks

Comment: You have to reshape your training data accordingly.

Comment: I edited,  this is my reshape I forgot it , X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1)) . would you correct it if you know.

Comment: it does not work with X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 30)) also

Comment: what is the shape of user_data?

Comment: I have 100 data. each one has 3 items, [1,2,3]. so I reshape It to (100,3,1). probably it is wrong. and my y_train is only 1 item but it can be one of 30 classes.

Comment: and what does y_train look like?

Comment: Y_train = user_data[:, 3] . y is 100 data with each 1 item

Comment: Updated my answer, you are reshaping your data correctly, but you are using the wrong loss. I have updated that to explain it further.

Comment: thanks , Y train is 30 different classes but not numbers from 0-29. but I have those 30 numbers separately. for example my Y train could be [12,34,984,1,4,...]

Comment: I used dummy data, you can use what ever you want, as long as there are total 30  unique classes and the data shape is the same as mine.

Comment: Hope that solves your problem. Do mark the solution if it does so it encourages me to further solve your questions in the future :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226057/discussion-between-akshay-sehgal-and-user9137963).